# How to add HTTPHeader to XJSONDataSource?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Tried this, but no luck, even do not know whether it is write way of implementation.

```
    Map<String, String> headers = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

    DSRequest request = new DSRequest();
    request.setHttpHeaders(headers);       

    XJSONDataSource ds = new XJSONDataSource();
    ds.setDataProtocol(DSProtocol.GETPARAMS);
    ds.setRequestProperties(request);
            ds.setDataURL("http://cross_domain");
    ds.fetchData();
```

I am trying for cross-domain calls to JSON services, if anyone have good example or tutorial please feel free to refer. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed headers from above code and started working seamlessly. I guess XJSONDataSource does not like headers.